# admin panel page blocking

Tags: php, session

blocking admin panel page. I did these codes, but the page always looks "unauthorized". Password true. When I do not do the session, I login successfully.
**http://localhost/admin/login.php?durum=unauthorized**

main.php

```
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

$ayarsor=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ayar where ayar_id=:id");
$ayarsor->execute(array('id' => 0));
$ayarcek=$ayarsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$kullanicisor=$db->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM admin 
                            where admin_nick=:nick");
$kullanicisor->execute(array('nick' => $_SESSION['admin_nick']));
$kullanicicek=$kullanicisor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$say=$kullanicisor->rowCount();

if ($say==0) {
    Header("Location:login.php?status=unauthorized");
    exit;
}
```

process.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['adminlogin'])) {

    $admin_nick=$_POST['admin_nick'];
    $admin_password=md5($_POST['admin_password']);

    $kullanicisor=$db->prepare("SELECT * 
                                FROM admin 
                                where admin_nick=:nick 
                                and admin_password=:password");
    $kullanicisor->execute(array(
        'nick' => $admin_nick,
        'password' => $admin_password
        ));

    echo $say=$kullanicisor->rowCount();

    if ($say==1) {
        $_SESSION['admin_nick']=$admin_nick;
        header("Location:main.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Location:login.php?durum=no");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Translate the title to English and this should be ok

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in both files? What is inside of `$_SESSION`?